# Android kontakt beacon detection onBeaconsDiscovered for ranging issue

Tags: android, uuid, ibeacon, seem-beacon-manager

```
onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region,List<BeaconDevice> beaconDevices)
```

This method doesn't detect beacons which are previously detected. 
Even when beacon is OFF, it remains in the vicinity.
Also, can you tell how to handle beacons in same vicinity?

Comment: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-android-beacon-ibeacon-detector/ this may help you

Comment: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: its workes according bluetooth  range covered, if beacons in rang then its detect On and if out of range then beacon Off Exit.